# How Set environment variables using Symfony CLI on windows 10

Tags: windows, environment-variables, single-page-application, symfony5

I'm working to build Single Page Application project (back-end in symfony as API and Preact in the front AS API consumer), and i have to set ENV_API_ENDPOINT on windows cmd prompt using this cmd :

```
sudo API_ENDPOINT=`symfony var:export SYMFONY_DEFAULT_ROUTE_URL --dir=..` yarn encore dev
```

But it doesn't work :  'API_ENDPOINT' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I want to set the API_ENDPOINT environment variable. How can I achieve it?

Comment: I recently went through this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64271807#comment113680026_64271807). It won't export it from your cloud config but hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

maybe with "set"?

set VARIABLE_TO_DEFINE=

```
set API_ENDPOINT=`symfony var:export SYMFONY_DEFAULT_ROUTE_URL --dir=..` yarn encore dev
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a little late but i had the same problem and i ended up running the command in git bash and that solved it for me!