# Symfony 5 and sudo commad using Windows 10

Tags: webpack, windows-10, hadoop-yarn, sudo, symfony5

I am following Fabien Potencier's book "Symfony 5: The Fast Track". I develop the project using Windows 10 pro 64 bit. The author of the book, however, works with Linux. In chapter 27 the following command should be executed, which works on Linux, but not on Windows 10:

sudo API_ENDPOINT = 'symfony var: export SYMFONY_DEFAULT_ROUTE_URL --dir = ..' yarn encore dev

I have installed Sudo for Windows, but the problem is not solved.

How do I run this command on Windws 10?

Comment: I read that chapter and I too think it's a little confusing. Maybe Fabien meant that you should write this (without sudo) in the .env (or .env.local) file?

Comment: Maybe not a command to run. But the end of the sentence invokes Yarn to be executed. I also found a summary of the commands mentioned in the book and it is the one that does not work for me. It's on the list, preceded by "sudo"

Comment: In the book Potencier write without sudo, but it does not clarify where the statement should be, in addition, the confusion is increased by being together with other Linux commands

Comment: From the book: "You could also run in the background now:

$ API_ENDPOINT=`symfony var:export SYMFONY_DEFAULT_ROUTE_URL --dir=..` symfony run -d --watch=webpack.config.js yarn encore dev --watch

Comment: It's clearly a command, but in Windows not work

Comment: He's just setting a variable. Try using a literal. How you do it depends on what shell are you using: for CMD `set API_ENDPOINT="http://my-api.example.com"`, for PowerShell `$env:API_ENDPOINT="..."`.

Comment: @msg: Thank you very much for your help! I still haven't fixed the problem but I think I'm on the right track thanks to your help. It is necessary to clarify that in this chapter of the book called "Step 27: Building a SPA", we work mainly with Yarn. In Yarn the variable takes the name: "npm_config_API_ENDPOINT": "SYMFONY_DEFAULT_ROUTE_URL" so the way to assign a value would be with the command: yarn config set npm_config_API_ENDPOINT 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @JorgeH After setting the variable, just running `yarn encore dev` should be enough, I'm not sure your way will work, as the var is not directly used by yarn, but webpack. You can find it in `webpack.config.js`. It's substituting its value in other parts of the code at compile time.